# Not running the lost focus event in a text box if another button is clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a data entry form and have code in the 'Lost Focus" event in each one of them.  But I also have other buttons that are not tab stop.  Example-Clear button, Check Input Button,and Exit Data Entry button as well as an Update Button ( I save all the entry in an access table then do a mass update to SQL Server, why I do that is a function of the requirement). But, if I click one of the buttons the lost focus event takes place, and I have to click the button again for it's code to run.  Is there a way around this, where I click the button and it negates the Lost Focus event from the field where the cursor is located?

Thanks

jpl

Comment: As soon as you click a control (e.g. a button), the other control has "lost focus" and its "Lost Focus" event will fire.  The "Lost Focus" event's main use is usually for data validation purposes - i.e. checking that the user hasn't left the field while it contains invalid data - which then allows other controls to be able to rely on the integrity of that data without having to recheck it themselves.  What are you using the "Lost Focus" event for?  And what in that code is stopping the control that is gaining focus to run its code?

Comment: Try `On Exit` instead of `Lost Focus`.

Comment: does on exit cause the data to be written to a file it it's in the last controlof the tab sequence? I use the lost focus to set proper case, etc. nothing major except in the first text box I get data from sql server based on the nunber entered.  Have never used on exit before.  Is it either/or lost, focus or on exit of can there be both?

Comment: Just changed all the lost focus events to on exit, an everything works fine and i can use the buttons as I want them to be.  Thanks for the help. jpl